# не срабатывает event.preventDefault(); в FF

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

[Сайт](https://veloolimp.com/index.php/cat/1/sort/ordered/direction/desc/page/2)

пагинация (ст.р 1,2,3), сортировки и т.д. я реализовал на ajax.

Хром, опера работают хорошо.
В ФФ же ajax срабатывает, но все равно происходит переход по УРЛ. 
т.е., судя по всему, не срабатывает `event.preventDefault();`
Я б его убрал, но для индексации вредно.

Консоль ФФ чиста. ошибок не возникает. В чем дело?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что Хром создает глобальный объект event, а мозилла нет. А вы скорее всего решили что event возникает по волшебству из ниоткуда. Но это не так - вам надо его передать в нужное место. Я посмотрел ваш код, вы можете сделать так

```
onclick="product_of_man(102);product_listing('');return false;"`
```

замените на

```
onclick="return product_of_man(102) && product_listing('') && false;"
```

Это должно решить вашу проблему, т.к. `return false` в обработчике эквивалентно `event.preventDefault()` и `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: не помогло.Более того, в Хроме при использовании 2х функций идет переход по ссылке   `<a onclick="return product_of_man(101) &amp;&amp; product_listing('') &amp;&amp; false;" href="https://veloolimp.com/index.php/cat/106/filter_id/101">DAYTONA</a>`

Comment: Где-то экранируются спецсимволы. Вообще старайтесь избегать инлайновый onclick - это почерк новичка, и вы только что напоролись на одну из причин почему так не стоит делать. Обойти экранирование символа `&` можно так - `onclick="return !~product_of_man(102) || !~product_listing('')` конструкция !~ что угодно в false превратит

Comment: Что опыта не хватает - спору нет! Как обойти? повесить `data-atrr` с параметрами. Добавить кнопкам селекторы и по ним по `.click `выполнять??

Comment: По хорошему вам надо вместо инлайновых onclick вешать обработчики из js после загрузки страницы, с помощью addEventListener. А данные,нужные для работы js и привязанные к конкретному html элементу кладите в data-атрибуты, и читайте опять же их из js. Обработчик первым аргументом принимает как раз тот `event`, о котором ваш вопрос, а вы его перетерли своими `''`, поэтому и не работает в FF.

Comment: @Kovalsky Да все верно. И не забудьте что у обработчика event первым аргументом.

Comment: Так и сделаю. @Darth   Спасибо!