# Не срабатывает вызов JS в Firefox и iphone

Tags: javascript, firefox

На странице 185.47.152.117/contact есть функционал, позволяющий на API Яндекс.Карты прокладывать маршрут.
На ярлыке кружка-метки это ссылка "Как проехать".
[image: Пример отработавшего скрипта - маршрут проложен]
Под IE, Opera, Chrome, на встроенном браузере android и на ipod скрипт отрабатывает нормально, вызывается окно запроса/коррекции исходного адреса и дальше построение маршрута. На FF окно ввода адреса не открывается.
Для вызова формы используется конструкция

```html
<a href="#" onclick="openModalPopup();return false;">Как проехать?</a>
```

Куда копать?

Comment: В консоли ошибки есть? Если есть - добавьте к вопросу, это сильно упростит дело

Comment: При клике на ссылку в консоль выведена ошибка: ReferenceError: event is not defined         contact:912:0

Comment: Кажется, починил. С подачи "посмотреть лог", убрал оператор event.preventDefault(); в функции openModalPopup - теперь и в FF работает, и в IE

Comment: посмотрите [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485102/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-event-preventdefault-%D0%B2-ff/485114)