# не работает event.target в Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, события

Заметила, что в Хроме все ок, а в ФФ не добавляет допэлемент, пишет, что не видит события, меня спасает валидация в ХТМЛ5, но вообще интересно, как это победить

```
`       let checkMaxWidth = function(elem = addAdditionalContainer){
        let inputForm = event.target;
        console.log(inputForm.parentNode);
        inputForm.parentNode.appendChild(addAdditionalContainer);
        event.preventDefault;
        return false;   
    };`
```

[Полный код проекта](https://jsfiddle.net/nagar_75/evs25rtL/1/)

[image: Debugger]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [не срабатывает event.preventDefault(); в FF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485102/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-event-preventdefault-%d0%b2-ff)

Comment: пишет, что не видит события и обойти нельзя, нужен целевой элемент

Comment: а почему просто не передать этот `event` в вызов `checkMaxWidth`?

Comment: Что должна показывать приложенная картинка?

Comment: именно в вызов а не в декларацию?

Comment: Вообще и туда и туда. у тебя checkMaxWidth - это обычная функция, что ты в нее передашь, то у тебя и будет доступно

Comment: Если в additional добавить как параметр event (ну и в вызов соответственно), в Хроме словишь windows is not defined и дальше windows.event FF тоже не поддерживается.

Comment: есть мысль использовать контекст this.event = ...

Answer (score -2):

Это особенности `IE8-`.

Вместо `event.target` в `IE8-` используется `event.srcElement`

Если писать обработчик, который будет поддерживать и `IE8-` и современные браузеры, то можно начать его так:

```
elem.onclick = function(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

  // ... теперь у нас есть объект события и target
  ...
}
```

Comment: Вы видимо читать не умеете...